# Search xml to find a node value corresponding to some input in unix

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, xpath

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:db2:CCTST1</connection-url>
    </local-tx-datasource>
    <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>jdbc/pvhrm_SLB_tu</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:db2:slbtst1</connection-url>
    </local-tx-datasource>
  </datasources>
```

I want to know the connection-url for a particular jndi-name using shell script.
Suppose the input is jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu then I want dbc:db2:CCTST1 as the output.
I am new to UNIX. I tried xmllint --xpath but getting error that xpath option not found.
Is there any other alternative.

Comment: Can you install XMLStarlet (http://xmlstar.sf.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

These lines could help you :

EDIT:

```
parameter=$(echo "YOURPARAMETER" | sed "s/\//\\\\\//g")  #e.g. : jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu
cat YOURXMLFILE| tr '\n' ' ' | sed "s/^.*<jndi-name>$parameter<\/jndi-name>[ ]*<connection-url>\(.\{14,17\}\)<\/connection-url>.*/\1\n/g"
```

In some words : 
- Enter your parameter : your jndi-name; the first sed expression will escape th slashes
- The tr expression will pu all on a sigle line
- The sed expression will replace "jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu
      jdbc:db2:CCTST1" by jdbc:db2:CCTST1 if it is correct.

This expression works, for a connection-url which has a length between 14&17 characters

Comment: I am getting the following error.                                  sed: command garbled: s/<jndi-name>jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu</jndi-name>\n<connection-url>\(*\)</connection-url>/\1/g

Comment: ok i edited the sed expression, it's quite horrible but it works... I hope it would help you ! :)

Comment: Works... for input *precisely* as given. Lots of other ways of writing the exact same XML structure wouldn't work, making this very fragile.

Comment: Yes sure, it depends on what you would like to do
A XML parser would be more sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You could install [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), after which you could do something like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//jndi-name[. = 'jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu']/following-sibling::connection-url" myfile.xml
```

Alternatively, you could install a newer version of [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) that has the `--xpath` option.

Comment: Good approach, but that's a rather convoluted way of writing the query, no?

Comment: Not sure about convoluted — I find it quite logical myself. That said, I do prefer your version; this was just the first version that popped into my head.

Answer (score 0):

Using XMLStarlet:

```
name=jdbc/pvhrm_CC_tu # example value
[[ $name = *"'"* ]] && { echo "ERROR: Injection attempt" >&2; exit 1; }
xmlstarlet sel \
  -t -m "//datasources[jndi-name='$name']/connection-url" -v . \
  <input.xml
```

The injection checking is probably excessive here, but a good habit to be in regardless whenever one substitutes data into code. (A better-designed interface would not allow such substitution at all, but always treat expansions as data rather than code).